# How to get Back button working between remote and local jQuery Mobile pages?

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a local jQuery Mobile project going (inside PhoneGap, thus file:// protocol) where I sometimes need to fetch external pages (using http://) from a server where the content too are jQM pages with almost identical markup (except for the content, which is generated from a CMS).

Setting $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages to true gives me the page, and that is all right. Going Back, however, fails. I get stuck in a place where /www/index.html is not found on the server (like, doh, of course..). Is there a way to "remember" where I came from, taking me back to the local html page I originally came from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We just added a docs page on PhoneGap in jQuery Mobile for RC3 that should help you out quite a bit:
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/phonegap.html

Comment: Thanks, a good start for this issue indeed. However, $.support.cors and $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages only enables me to do the fetching alright, not enabling the back button thingie.

Comment: Just to clarify, it's not primarily a PhoneGap issue. The same thing happens if I use the file:// protocol directly in Safari - I can't go back from a ajaxed-fetched page which originated from an online page.

Comment: Dang, sorry Todd. I completely missed pushStateEnabled = false. That solved it, thanks!