# How to navigate from a webpage to local page in my phonegap app?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, navigation

I have a phonegap app running on my phone. I have a link that takes me to a web page to check some info and presents some data... then I want to be able to have a back button so that the user will navigate back to the local app. Is this possible in both android and iOS?

Comment: Its for the appstore or webpage?

Comment: Related but not identical question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137909/how-to-get-back-button-working-between-remote-and-local-jquery-mobile-pages (that one is JQM specific)

Comment: @user969275 did you find any suitable solution

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use [childbrowser](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowser) plugin of phonegap as in that case you will have consistent behavior in both android and iOS considering iOS does not have `backbutton` to go back to the application.

[Childbrowser for Android](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowser)

[Childbrowser for iOS](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/ChildBrowser)

Comment: +1 on childbrowser. UI-wise it will add a toolbar to the top of ios apps that give the user a BACK button to get back to your app. On other platforms that have hardware conventions (i.e. a back button) no toolbar will show. Also, childbrowser is slated to become part of cordova/phonegap "core" functionality after 2.0.

Comment: A toolbar that looks like a browser is exactly what I'm trying to avoid by using Phonegap in the first place.

Comment: toolbar is to support the ui, as in iOS you do not have any other way to switch or go back. You can still customize the ui of childbrowser as you copy the source related to that in you project - https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/phonegap/jbXi-K7BBno

Comment: please check this source, i have added an option in plugin to hide/show address bar as required. https://github.com/dhavaln/cordova-examples/tree/master/android-cordova-childbrowser

Comment: thanks for your answer.I got working by using the childbrowser plugin.

Answer (score 3):

This works in both Android and iOS:

```js
window.history.go( -( history.length - 1 ) );
```

But, as others have mentioned, I've found it not worth it to try to ever leave the `UIWebView`. After you get back to your app page, things occasionally don't work as expected. I've noticed that PhoneGap gets unloaded and there appears to be no way to reload it.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is **"NO WAY BACK"**.
 You can navigate within your Local App (classes any number of times)

 Once you send the flow to

```
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

You cannot Navigate back to any local class.

Answer (score 1):

I hacked a custom version of the ChildBrowser to remove all toolbar elements and also pass messages between the child page and the parent app. This hack, [SlaveBrowser](https://github.com/dda/slavebrowser), was originally intended for oAuth2 on Android. The parent app knows when to close the external page, so there was no need for an ugly toolbar :-). Someone with Obj-C skills could port that to iOS

Answer (score 0):

If your webpages are stored in your project under /assets/ you can use file:///android_asset/index.html.

Of course, that is Android specific.

Answer (score 0):

what about displaying the external page in an iframe. this way you can still display a back-button from you local phonegap app.

Comment: That's a start of a solution.  So then how does the page in the iframe send a message to the parent frame telling it to navigate?

Comment: Hm. My initial Idea was that you display a small navigation bar on top of your page and underneath it an iFrame with the external page. This way you could display the backbutton on your navbar. In the same way Google displays some information on image search results http://www.google.de/imgres?hl=de&biw=1150&bih=588&gbv=2&tbm=isch&tbnid=HhYIr-Oz_5sLkM:&imgrefurl=http://www.crossmedia-zentrum.de/cms/%3Fp%3D451%3FKeepThis%3Dtrue%26TB_iframe%3Dtrue%26height%3D450%26width%3D550&docid=q0eY140VMgaNgM&imgurl=http://www.crossmedia-zentrum.de/cms/wp-content/gallery/keylearnings/apple.jpg

Answer (score 0):

If you have complete control of the content of the external page, you could implement a URL scheme in iOS: http://remysharp.com/2010/09/01/custom-url-schemes-in-phonegap/

... and this hack to get it in Android: http://remysharp.com/2010/09/01/custom-url-schemes-in-phonegap/

Then your external page could link back to the app via a myappname://some/parameters URL

Both of the above articles are from 2010, which does not bode well for the Android one (software is constantly evolving)... but if that doesn't work I bete there is a more recent article somewhere with a way that works for sure. I know the iOS one works as it is in use in my app now.

Answer (score 0):

I have used childbrowser and modified the UI in xCode so that I have no address bar and an unique small "go back to the app" button. I didn't need to touch obj-c just in the UI editor select what u don't want and delete it.